# Unicode/utf-8 characters in AngularJS routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode, utf-8, hebrew

I'm interested in using readable routes with hebrew characters in them in an AngularJS application:

```
http://localhost/#!/project/מה+המצב
```

However, when I run the URL through the AngularJS router, the browser address bar shows the following URL:

```
http://localhost/#!/project/%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91
```

I have tried to navigate to the URL on a simple page, without angular, and the URL shows up fine in the address bar, which leads me to believe that AngularJS is the culprit.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable html5 mode (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` in app configuration). Than browser will correctly display utf8 characters in address bar.